# bash uncompress dynamically-names gz and store in variable

Tags: bash

I need to store the result filename of running `gunzip file.gz` into a variable. [The only answer I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177113/bash-uncompress-gz-and-store-in-variable) is for when the name of the file is known ahead of time. However, in my case, the `.gz` file is going to be dynamically generated, so the accepted answer doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
cd /var/www/backup/db
DB_TAR=$( /usr/bin/ls site_name* -Rt | /usr/bin/head -1 )
DB=$( gunzip ${DB_TAR} )
echo "${DB}"
```

but got nothing in the output.

Comment: Do you know the gzip file's name once it has been generated? If so the linked question's accepted answer seems to fit your needs (the `$file` part is dynamic, you can just remove the `.fastq` that isn't relevant to you and it should work)

Comment: please edit your Q to show an assignment, i.e. `DB_TAR=....` . Good luck.

Comment: `gunzip "$file"` doesn't emit anything to stdout, so your variable can't be expected to capture anything. You need to use `gunzip -c "$file"`. And note that [parsing `ls` is extremely error-prone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @Aaron it'll differ every time

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the -c flag prints out the entire database dump

Comment: @crashspringfield, yes, and that's what you said you wanted, right? The database dump stored in your variable?

Comment: No, I need the file name

Comment: Does your question say that anywhere?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry. editted it to make it more clear

Comment: BTW, the use of lower-case variable names in my answer is deliberate; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities* -- keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named preexisting environment variable, so the namespace guidelines necessarily apply to both categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /var/www/backup/db || exit
{ IFS= read -r -d ' ' timestamp && IFS= read -r -d '' latest; } < <(
  find site_name* -type f -name '*.gz' -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -znr
)
gunzip -- "$latest" || exit
uncompressed_latest="${latest%.gz}"
echo "$uncompressed_latest"
```

---

- Parsing `ls` is innately error-prone; [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) describes more reliable ways to find the newest/oldest/etc file, one of which (albeit requiring GNU `find` and `sort`) is used here.
- Stripping a known suffix is best done with [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). `${var%suffix}` returns the contents of `var`, with the shortest possible match for the pattern `suffix` removed.

Comment: I don't need the uncompressed content, I need the file name.

Comment: **Oh**. So you just want to know how to strip `.gz` off the end of a variable's contents?

Comment: It worked once I removed `%T@` from `printf`. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have the `%T@`, it isn't sorting by time anymore (unless your filenames are themselves in sort order). Better to adjust the `read` to ignore the timestamp.

Comment: @crashspringfield, ...see recent edit, showing how to use two separate `read`s, one which reads (and discards) the timestamp, the other of which reads the filename.